# html table width not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table

I'm building a webpage for the mother of a friend of mine who is starting up a massage practice and so far everything works good, but I'm having troubles with the prices.

I display the prices in a table so you can see the description/duration/price in a nice and easy to look at layout, but for some reason this only works at a desktop pc/laptop, but when looking at the prices with a mobile devices, it screws up the width set for the tables.

This is my code:

```
<table class="Titel1">
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Gezichtsmassage</td>
      <td width="80">20 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 15,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Gezichts-  en hoofdhuidmassage</td>
      <td width="80">30 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 20,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Hoofdhuidmassage</td>
      <td width="80">20 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 15,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Voetmassage</td>
      <td width="80">20 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 15,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Voetmassage  incl. voetbad</td>
      <td width="80">30 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 22,50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) gedeeltelijk</td>
      <td width="80">30 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 22,50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) full body</td>
      <td width="80">60 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 35,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Ontspanningsmasssage  (BSR) full body</td>
      <td width="80">90 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 50,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Zwangerschapsmassage</td>
      <td width="80">60 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 37,50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Zwangerschapsmassage  met partner*</td>
      <td width="80">60 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 42,50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Hotstone</td>
      <td width="80">30 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 17,50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Combinatie  hotstone- en ontspanningsmassage</td>
      <td width="80">90 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 55,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
      <td width="80">30 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 20,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="335">Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
      <td width="80">60 Minuten</td>
      <td width="55">€ 35,00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is what is in my style script:

```
.Titel1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this cause I'm getting out of ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to switch from using pixels to % for a more fluid display that works on mobile and websites.

To improve this I would remove all the widths and do this all in CSS.

```
<table class="Titel1">
<tr>
  <td>Gezichtsmassage</td>
  <td>20 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Gezichts-  en hoofdhuidmassage</td>
  <td>30 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hoofdhuidmassage</td>
  <td>20 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Voetmassage</td>
  <td>20 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Voetmassage  incl. voetbad</td>
  <td>30 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 22,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) gedeeltelijk</td>
  <td>30 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 22,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) full body</td>
  <td>60 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 35,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ontspanningsmasssage  (BSR) full body</td>
  <td>90 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 50,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Zwangerschapsmassage</td>
  <td>60 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 37,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Zwangerschapsmassage  met partner*</td>
  <td>60 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 42,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hotstone</td>
  <td>30 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 17,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Combinatie  hotstone- en ontspanningsmassage</td>
  <td>90 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 55,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
  <td>30 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
  <td>60 Minuten</td>
  <td>€ 35,00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
.Titel1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.Titel1 tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 70%;
}

.Titel1 tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 15%;
}

.Titel1 tr td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the width of the elements inside the `<td>` element but inside CSS:

```
<table class="Titel1">
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Gezichtsmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">20 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Gezichts-  en hoofdhuidmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">30 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Hoofdhuidmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">20 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Voetmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">20 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Voetmassage  incl. voetbad</td>
  <td class="minutes">30 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 22,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) gedeeltelijk</td>
  <td class="minutes">30 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 22,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Ontspanningsmassage  (BSR) full body</td>
  <td class="minutes">60 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 35,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Ontspanningsmasssage  (BSR) full body</td>
  <td class="minutes">90 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 50,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Zwangerschapsmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">60 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 37,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Zwangerschapsmassage  met partner*</td>
  <td class="minutes">60 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 42,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Hotstone</td>
  <td class="minutes">30 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 17,50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Combinatie  hotstone- en ontspanningsmassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">90 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 55,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">30 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 20,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="descriptions">Rug-,  nek-, en schoudermassage</td>
  <td class="minutes">60 Minuten</td>
  <td class="price">€ 35,00</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.price {
    width: 55px;
}

.minutes {
    width: 80px;
}

.descriptions {
    width: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/epHsH/

Comment: thx a lot guys! works like a charm now :) now i can finally do the final touches of the webpage :)